# Map reduce input format

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am very new in hadoop. and want input int like this to mapper:

1 2 3 4//////6 7 8

3 3 2 1//////5 9 0

=====////////-----

key /////////    value

first fourth in key and next 3 number in value?
would you plzz help me to write it in java in mapper class?

I dont want read it from file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what do mean by "dont want read it from file". I think what you need to do is read each line from the file and split each line by '//////'.

```
public static class MapClass extends MapReduceBase implements
        Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
            OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter)
            throws IOException {
        String line = value.toString();
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, "//////",
                false);
        word.set("key:"+tokenizer.nextToken());
        output.collect(word, new Text("value="+tokenizer.nextToken()));
    }
}
```

Comment: thnx very much vinnie means read my input data from mapreduce code

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you could split the key from the value *before* the mapper which I imagine is an easier way to do what you're trying to do. It can be done by using KeyValueTextInputFormat as your input class. This does exactly what you need; it allows you to choose the delimiter/separator that splits the key from the value that is passed to the mapper. You would set it by doing:

`job.setInputFormatClass(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);`

Then you would choose your separator by typing:

`Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("mapreduce.input.keyvaluelinerecordreader.key.value.separator","//////");`

Then when it arrives to your mapper, it's already split.

Comment: dear Eric when i want use this conf tell me: The method setInputFormatClass(Class<? extends InputFormat>) in the type Job is not applicable for the arguments (Class<KeyValueTextInputFormat>)